# Trying to understand this function: Array.prototype.reverse = function() {

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

When this method is called, it reverses the order of the items in the original array. Then then it returns that same, original array. No new arrays should need to be created to pass this kata.
However, I'm trying to figure out how `this.push(arr.pop());` works in this function.

```
Array.prototype.reverse = function() {
  var arr = this.splice(0);  //I understand first we remove all the items in the array starting from [0]

  while(arr.length) {    //then we run the arr.length of all the items? 
    this.push(arr.pop());  //then add the deleted last item? doesn't make sense...
  }   

  return this;
};
```

test cases:

```
Test.assertSimilar([1, 2, 3, 4].reverse(), [4,3,2,1]);
Test.assertSimilar(["a", "b", "c"].reverse(), ["c", "b", "a"]);
Test.assertSimilar([].reverse(), []);
```

or please write a function you think is a better solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've added comments:

```
Array.prototype.reverse = function() {
  var arr = this.splice(0);  // Removes all entries from `this` array AND returns
                             // them in a new array

  while(arr.length) {        // For as long as that new array still has items
                             // (length is "truthy" until it's 0)
    this.push(arr.pop());    // `pop` removes the LAST entry from `arr`, and
                             // `push` adds it to `this` as the next entry
  }   

  return this;
};
```

So say we have `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`:

1. First those are removed from `this` and put in `arr`.
2. Then, because `arr.length` is `5`, we enter the body of the loop.
3. `arr.pop()` removes `5` from `arr`.
4. `this.push()` adds `5` to the next available location in `this`, which is at the beginning
5. `arr.length` is now `4`, so we go into the body again
6. `arr.pop()` removes `4` from `arr`.
7. `this.push()` adds `4` to the next available location in `this`, which is just after `5`
8. Rinse, repeat
9. When `arr.length` is `0`, it's not truthy anymore, and we exit the loop

Answer (score 1):

> *"or please write a function you think is a better solution"*

Here's a more efficient and simpler solution:

```
Array.prototype.reverse = function() {
  for (var i = 0, j = this.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
    var tmp = this[i];
    this[i] = this[j];
    this[j] = tmp;
  }
  return this;
};
```

---

In browsers that support ECMAScript 6, you can shorten it to this:

```
Array.prototype.reverse = function() {
  for (var i = 0, j = this.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
    [this[i], this[j]] = [this[j], this[i]];
  }
  return this;
};
```

Not sure if there's any extra overhead.